# JSoup - Error extracting contents of a div

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm working on an Android project and I'm currently playing around with JSoup to extract data from a website for the application.

The website I'm targeting is [here](http://www.last.fm/music/Bright+Eyes).

And I want to extract the main information text. The xpath for that div is

`//div[@id='wikiAbstract']`

My complete code is as follows

```
public class Main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   Document doc = null;

   try {
       doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.last.fm/music/Bright+Eyes").get();

   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   Element divs = doc.select("div#wikiAbstract").first();
   tv.setText(divs.text());
```

}

However, I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception. I have tested the same code on other websites and divs and it works perfectly. I can't understand why this is different.

I would appreciate any help/feedback from anyone, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, ok so the html content from [here](http://www.last.fm/music/Bright+Eyes) was coming from the mobile version of the last.fm website so the div id's were different.

For anyone who might encounter this, you can add a user-agent request header to the connection to ensure the full website is requested or just ensure you get the correct div id's from the mobile site

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(myURL)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1")
                .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This complete program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.last.fm/music/Bright+Eyes").get();
    Element content = doc.select("div#wikiAbstract").first();
    System.out.println(content.text());
}
```

Outputs (shortened):

> Bright Eyes is a band consisting mainly of American singer, guitarist,
>   and songwriter Conor Oberst. Bright Eyes also features
>   multi-instrumentalist/producer Mike Mogis, keyboard player Nate
>   Walcott and a rotating lineup of collaborators drawn primarily from
>   Omaha, Nebraska, and the...

...which is to say that your **error lies elsewhere**. Maybe `textView` is `null`?

The **general lesson** here is that it pays to extract out the portion you think is failing and confirm your suspicion before moving on.